# Angular 2 - conditional styling for descendants

Tags: css, angular, ng-class, ng-style

```css
.parent {
  color: blue;
}

.parent * {
  color: red;
}

.child {
  color: black;
}

.grandchild {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Parent
  <div>Child
    <div>GrandChild</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Say I have a property called toggle in the Angular component. I would like to toggle ".parent *" style for the descendants so their color would change between red or blue depending on the toggle state. How can I do so through ngClass or ngStyle? Or is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

simply do it with `[class.parent]`

```
<div [class.parent]="toggle">
 Parent
 <div>Child
  <div>GrandChild</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

the class parent will be applied with when `toggle` is true.

Comment: Babar, that works like a charm! What I don't understand is how come class.parent takes the class from .parent * but not .parent. The angular documentation doesn't explain that: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html.

Comment: Try to invert their order in the css file. Last definition wins in CSS for same specificity.